# Issue with Custom Post Type Tags

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I cannot get TAGS to work within my custom post types.

I have the following to establish my custom post type:

```
function Work() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Work', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Work', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Work' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Work' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Work' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Work' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Work' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Work' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Work Found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Work Found In The Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Work'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our Work and Work specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category')

    );
    register_post_type( 'Work', $args );
```

If I take: 'taxonomies' => array('category') and edit to array('tags') nothing happens. Shouldn't that make tags work with my custom post type?

I also found this code:

```
function reg_tag() {
         register_taxonomy_for_object_type('post_tag', 'CUSTOM_POST_TYPE');
}
add_action('init', 'reg_tag');
```

and added it to my functions file as well, but no luck with that either.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `'taxonomies' => array( 'post_tag' )` to add tags support for a custom post type, like this:

```
function Work() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'               => _x( 'Work', 'post type general name' ),
        'singular_name'      => _x( 'Work', 'post type singular name' ),
        'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'Work' ),
        'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Work' ),
        'new_item'           => __( 'New Work' ),
        'all_items'          => __( 'All Work' ),
        'view_item'          => __( 'View Work' ),
        'search_items'       => __( 'Search Work' ),
        'not_found'          => __( 'No Work Found' ),
        'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No Work Found In The Trash' ), 
        'parent_item_colon'  => '',
        'menu_name'          => 'Work'
    );
    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'description'   => 'Holds our Work and Work specific data',
        'public'        => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'excerpt', 'comments' ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),

    );
    register_post_type( 'Work', $args );
}
```

Comment: u r welcome! if the answer resolves your issue, then mark it as correct and vote up it :D